# Convert SQL Server SQL query to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Below is the SQL Server query I want to convert to MySQL:

```
SELECT SaleDetail.cTaxiNo, Category.cCarName, qryDriverExpenses.nAmount,
       Sale.nInvoiceNo, Sale.cCustomerName, IIf([cPackageType] ='GENERAL', 
       [nProviderRate],[nProviderRate]/[nProviderKM]) AS nARate, SaleDetail.nKM, 
       SaleDetail.nAmount, Sale.dInvoiceDate, qryFuel.nAmount, 
       SaleDetail.nProviderKM, SaleDetail.nProviderRate
FROM qryFuel 
RIGHT JOIN (((Sale INNER JOIN SaleDetail ON Sale.nSalePk = SaleDetail.nSalePk) 
INNER JOIN (CarMaster 
INNER JOIN Category 
ON CarMaster.nCategoryPk = Category.nCategoryPK) ON SaleDetail.cTaxiNo = 
     CarMaster.cCarNo) 
LEFT JOIN qryDriverExpenses 
    ON SaleDetail.nTourBookingpk = qryDriverExpenses.nTourBookingPK) 
ON qryFuel.nTourBookingPK = 
     SaleDetail.nTourBookingpk

ORDER BY Sale.nInvoiceNo, Sale.dInvoiceDate;
```

I am getting error sql

> syntax error . near [cPackageType]

Please help on this!

Comment: There is no IIF in MYSQL,, use IF instead ;  If([cPackageType] ='GENERAL', 
[nProviderRate],[nProviderRate]/[nProviderKM]) AS nARate,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IIf` in `SQL Server` is `If` in `MySQL`

```
SELECT SaleDetail.cTaxiNo, Category.cCarName, qryDriverExpenses.nAmount,
   Sale.nInvoiceNo, Sale.cCustomerName, 
   IF(cPackageType ='GENERAL', nProviderRate, nProviderRate/nProviderKM) AS nARate, 
   SaleDetail.nKM, SaleDetail.nAmount, Sale.dInvoiceDate, qryFuel.nAmount, 
    SaleDetail.nProviderKM, SaleDetail.nProviderRate
FROM qryFuel RIGHT JOIN 
(((Sale INNER JOIN SaleDetail ON Sale.nSalePk =            
  SaleDetail.nSalePk) INNER JOIN (CarMaster INNER JOIN Category ON 
 CarMaster.nCategoryPk = Category.nCategoryPK) ON SaleDetail.cTaxiNo = 
 CarMaster.cCarNo) LEFT JOIN qryDriverExpenses ON SaleDetail.nTourBookingpk 
 = qryDriverExpenses.nTourBookingPK) 
 ON qryFuel.nTourBookingPK = SaleDetail.nTourBookingpk    
ORDER BY Sale.nInvoiceNo, Sale.dInvoiceDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using those sort of joins are just asking for trouble.  Please study up on proper joining syntax, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517%28v=sql.105%29.aspx.  Here is formatted query:

```
SELECT SaleDetail.cTaxiNo
,Category.cCarName
,qryDriverExpenses.nAmount
,Sale.nInvoiceNo
,Sale.cCustomerName
,CASE WHEN `cPackageType` ='GENERAL' THEN 
        `nProviderRate`
    ELSE
        `nProviderRate`/`nProviderKM`
    END AS nARate
,SaleDetail.nKM
,SaleDetail.nAmount
,Sale.dInvoiceDate
,qryFuel.nAmount
,SaleDetail.nProviderKM
,SaleDetail.nProviderRate
FROM qryFuel 
INNER JOIN SaleDetail
    ON qryFuel.nTourBookingPK = SaleDetail.nTourBookingpk
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Sale
    ON Sale.nSalePk = SaleDetail.nSalePk
INNER JOIN CarMaster 
    ON SaleDetail.cTaxiNo = CarMaster.cCarNo
INNER JOIN Category 
    ON CarMaster.nCategoryPk = Category.nCategoryPK
LEFT OUTER JOIN qryDriverExpenses 
    ON SaleDetail.nTourBookingpk = qryDriverExpenses.nTourBookingPK
ORDER BY Sale.nInvoiceNo, Sale.dInvoiceDate;
```

Comment: Actually TSQL + SQL Server does use IIF https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213574.aspx. Also the op is trying to convert from SQL Server to MySQL

Comment: Ah, I keep forgetting they added it in 2012.  Thanks!

Comment: Also the query will still throw the same error, due to the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SaleDetail.cTaxiNo, Cate;ry.cCarName, qryDriverExpenses.nAmount,
   Sale.nInvoiceNo, Sale.cCustomerName, If(`cPackageType` ='GENERAL', 
`nProviderRate`,`nProviderRate`/`nProviderKM`) AS nARate, SaleDetail.nKM, 
SaleDetail.nAmount, Sale.dInvoiceDate, qryFuel.nAmount, 
SaleDetail.nProviderKM, SaleDetail.nProviderRate


  FROM qryFuel RIGHT JOIN (((Sale INNER JOIN SaleDetail ON Sale.nSalePk =            
  SaleDetail.nSalePk) INNER JOIN (CarMaster INNER JOIN Cate;ry ON 
 CarMaster.nCate;ryPk = Cate;ry.nCate;ryPK) ON SaleDetail.cTaxiNo = 
 CarMaster.cCarNo) LEFT JOIN qryDriverExpenses ON SaleDetail.nTourBookingpk 
 = qryDriverExpenses.nTourBookingPK) ON qryFuel.nTourBookingPK = 
 SaleDetail.nTourBookingpk

   ORDER BY Sale.nInvoiceNo, Sale.dInvoiceDate;
```

Quoted column names should be surrounded by ticks, not square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. MySQL uses IF rather than IIF and doesn't much like square brackets either:

```
SELECT SaleDetail.cTaxiNo, Category.cCarName, qryDriverExpenses.nAmount,
   Sale.nInvoiceNo, Sale.cCustomerName, If(cPackageType ='GENERAL', 
nProviderRate,nProviderRate/nProviderKM) AS nARate, SaleDetail.nKM, 
SaleDetail.nAmount, Sale.dInvoiceDate, qryFuel.nAmount, 
SaleDetail.nProviderKM, SaleDetail.nProviderRate


  FROM qryFuel RIGHT JOIN (((Sale INNER JOIN SaleDetail ON Sale.nSalePk =            
  SaleDetail.nSalePk) INNER JOIN (CarMaster INNER JOIN Category ON 
 CarMaster.nCategoryPk = Category.nCategoryPK) ON SaleDetail.cTaxiNo = 
 CarMaster.cCarNo) LEFT JOIN qryDriverExpenses ON SaleDetail.nTourBookingpk 
 = qryDriverExpenses.nTourBookingPK) ON qryFuel.nTourBookingPK = 
 SaleDetail.nTourBookingpk

   ORDER BY Sale.nInvoiceNo, Sale.dInvoiceDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

IIF is not valid in MySQL

change

```
IIf([cPackageType] ='GENERAL', 
       [nProviderRate],[nProviderRate]/[nProviderKM]) AS nARate
```

to

```
if [cPackageType] = 'GENERAL' then nProviderRate 
 else nProviderRate/nProviderKM
end as nARate
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a different approach since being on a MAC has some limitation to working with SQL Server.

Converting MS SQL Server to MySQL.  These simple command line commands will get you 90% there for Free and save hours.

```
#Remove the '[' character
sed -i '' -e 's/\]//g' *.sql
#Remove the ']' character
sed -i '' -e 's/\[//g' *.sql
#Add a semicolon to the end of each line (INSERT commands)
sed -i '' -e '/[^;] *$/s/$/;/' *.sql
#Replace the dbo. before each table name
sed -i '' -e 's/INSERT dbo./INSERT INTO /g' *.sql
#Replace remove any remaining dbo.
sed -i '' -e 's/dbo.//g' *.sql
```

Scenario: You want a simple local database for development to mock a SQL Server on a Mac.  Avoid Docker SQL Server setup, and no Microsoft Management Console on Mac.

Find a MS Windows PC and export the database tables with Microsoft Management Console with data.  These will create .sql files for each table.

For very large files, you will want to 'chunk' them with a Python script.  Use chatGPT to write the script for you if not familiar with Python.  MySQL Workbench will start crawling with large file sets.

Then all we have to do is adjust the CREATE TABLE, whatever you do manually you can derive another sed command line to automate it.

Go further, if you have multiple directories of .sql files, then you can use the 'find' command followed by the 'sed' command to perform the manipulation recursively.